# Using AJAX to create a datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datalist

I'm trying to add to a datalist using AJAX. The webpage I'm requesting just has names of cities each on their own line. I basically have:

```
(function() {
"use strict";

    window.onload = function() {
        fetch("cities");
    };

    function fetch(mode) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onload = getCities();
        request.open("GET", "https://weather.com/weather/mode=" + mode, true);
        request.send();
    }

    function getCities() {
        //loop while there's data/string to grab {
            var city = document.createElement("option"); 
            city.innerHTML = this.responseText; //set the option as the name of the city from the request
            document.getElementById("cities").appendChild(city);
        }
    }
}) ();
```

The webpage is just a filler for a webpage that I'm using on a server but I'm trying to create a new option tag for each string and append it to a datalist in my html but I'm having an issue catching anything. For some reason I'm just getting an undefined error. Sorry I'm kind of new to javascript and AJAX.

webpage layout of the page of requesting:

Abidjan
Accra
Adana
Addis Abeba
Ahmedabad
Aleppo
Alexandria
Alger
Almaty
Ankara
Anshan
Baghdad
Baku
Bandung
Bangalore
Bangkok

Comment: Shouldn't it be `request.send();`?

Comment: ahh that may be the issue

Comment: fixed that but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: You could add the line `debugger;` into any of your functions, and then open Chrome Developer Tools > Console, and finally reload the page. The debugger should stop at the breakpoint, and you can step through the functions using the little arrows on the right for Step Over, etc.

Comment: it should be `getCities()` too - you need to add the brackets to execute the function

Answer (score 0):

You're missing brackets `()` off your function calls

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    window.onload = function() {
        fetch("cities");
    };

    function fetch(mode) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onload = getCities();      // <- brackets missing here
        request.open("GET", "https://weather.com/weather/mode=" + mode, true);
        request.send();                    // <- and here
    }

    function getCities() {
        var city = document.createElement("option");
        document.getElementById("cities").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
}) ();
```

It's also very unclear to me how your `getCities` function is supposed to work. You're creating an option set, but not adding it to your DOM. I'm also not sure what `this.responseText` is supposed to be.

Comment: It's not finished yet because I wasn't sure what I was getting from the request return. I want to iterate through with a loop and each iteration create a new option tag containing the city name in the inner html and then append it to my datalist but I haven't gotten that far because I keep running into an issue.

Comment: the webpage I'm requesting just has:

Abidjan
Accra
Adana
Addis Abeba
Ahmedabad
Aleppo
Alexandria
Alger
Almaty
Ankara
Anshan
Baghdad
Baku
Bandung
Bangalore
Bangkok

and i'm trying to add each of these as an option in my datalist.